# How to make all kind of links clickable in Android textview from Rich text/html string

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, textview, android-jetpack

I have some rich texts returned from api which may have phone-numbers, raw text-links, hyperlinks email. I want to make everything clickable using Android textview.

for an example :

```html
<p>Hello <i>Mr.Foo</i>.<br>Thank you for visiting us.<br>
<br>For more details, click this link:&nbsp;<a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">My Web Link</a>
<br> You can also visit another website: www.anotherweb.com <br><br> 
<b>For any enquiries:<br>
<br>Mr.Boo</b>
<br>Contact: (65) 1020 2401 / +6512345678<br>
Email: booking@example.com<br><br>
</p>
```

As you can see there are

- 1 hyperlink with `<a href="">` tag,
- 1 raw text web link ( [www.anotherweb.com](http://www.anotherweb.com) )
- 1 email address without `<a href="mailto:..` tag)
- 2 phone numbers

I tried to use following (along with `Html.fromHtml()` )

1. `Textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` :

   Hyperlinks become clickable but email, phone number or raw text links unable to click.
2. Used `autoLink="all"` in Textview :

   Everything else worked except hyperlinks( the one with `<a href="">` become not clickable)
3. Used `Linkify.addLinks(textview, Linkify.ALL)` :

   Again unable to click on hyperlinks but others worked fine.

I tried also combination of these but couldn't make everything clickable at once. Is there any other way exist?

Comment: Try this library -> https://github.com/saket/Better-Link-Movement-Method

Comment: that make no difference. still hyper links( <a href="">) are not clickable.